# How to write this if statement in python/selenium/scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a trouble scraping the website because some of the same elements are just in a different class_name. So im trying to create a if statement to search the class first and if its not present it would move on to next class.

```
            driver.get("https://wormbase.org/#012-34-5")
            search = driver.find_element_by_id("Search")
            search.send_keys(cdi)
            search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

for this part i would like to add an if statement saying if id1 is not present then move on the id

```
            if id1 =! : # still not sure how to create the if statement

            id = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "locus")))
            id1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "highlight")))

            
            description = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "text-min")))

            data['Gene_name'] = id.text
            data['Description'] = description.text
```

Comment: Selenium `find_element_by_id()` returns an error if it it doesn't find the element, so you meet to use `try except` instead of `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use `if` statement you have to use

`find_elements_by_id("some id")`

instead of

`find_element_by_id("some id")`

in this case you will have list with one element if the required element is present on the page and empty list if not.

```
ids = driver.find_elements_by_id("some id")
if ids:
    # do something fo example
    ids[0].click()
else:
    # try to search it again or do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find the length by using:

```
elementLength=driver.find_elements_by_id("id")
```

Then, if `len(elementLength)>0`, go to the first class, and otherwise go to another.